# Anyway to group or sort dates by month and/or year using python?

Tags: python, date, time-series, data-science

Looking at a fruit and veg dataset with prices and dates. However when I try to plot anything with the date there are way too many instances as the date feature does it by each week. Is there anyway to either group the dates by month or something? The date format is like 2022-02-11.

Comment: Could you show your code? Do you use pandas or what framework?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to add a month column and group by it. We use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pandas.DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) to do this.

```
df['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date).month
df.groupby(['Month']).sum().plot()
```